# How to determine if I should post on Stack Overflow or Server Fault about SQL

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, serverfault, site-recommendation

How can I determine in a clear way whether my SQL question should be on Stack Overflow or Server Fault?

I have a few SQL questions, but I can't state in a clear way why any of them belongs on Stack Overflow or Server Fault.
I'm trying to find a checklist. I know I should always use discernment, but how can I do that in a more clear way?

A lot of SQL questions touch the Server and Infra configurations.
But how do we set rules to determine what is considered a good question for Server Fault and what is considered a good question for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, ask yourself: is it about programming or configuration of the server?

Is your question about ...

- ... how to write a SQL statement/query, it belongs on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).
- ... how to configure or maintain the server, it belongs on [SF](https://serverfault.com/).
- ... how to maintain the server via SQL, it belongs on [SF](https://serverfault.com/).
- ... the right design pattern for Tables, it belongs on [PR](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).
- ... optimal performance tweaks, it belongs on [SF](https://serverfault.com/).
- ...

Some examples about what your questions are, would help, too.

**Edit:** As to your question: That depends, is your question about database replication, it belongs on [SF](https://serverfault.com/), is your question about how to write a script for it, it belongs on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: sorry what is PR? So script several databases replication is supposed to be on SF?

Comment: @Gabriel Guimarães: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks your answer definetly maked things clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Bobby wrote a nice specific answer for you. Here are some general rules of thumb to satisfy the implied question in your last sentence:

Stack Overflow is for software developers.
SO questions are about programming languages and computer code.

Server Fault is for system administrators.
SF questions are about setting up and maintaining large computer systems.