# Is the following question type OK in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if I should post on Stack Overflow or Server Fault about SQL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70299/how-to-determine-if-i-should-post-on-stack-overflow-or-server-fault-about-sql)

I want to describe how I am handling a SQL (MySQL) query, and want to know if there are other options? Is that an OK question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: What do you mean by "how I am handling"? The database engine handles queries, you usually write them (or try to read/understand/fix/make the go fast)

Comment: Just ask the question. Be as clear as you can about what the problem is - is it failing?, returning the wrong result? etc. If Stack Overflow is not the right place and it's a good question it can be migrated to other sites like http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your desired purposes, I would use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers interested in sharing code for peer review.